# jsonmap issue in struts2-jquery-grid

Tags: struts2-jquery-grid

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="campaignCreatives" jsonmap="
function(obj){
  return obj.campaignCreatives;
}" 
index="campaignCreatives" 
title="Creatives" 
editable="true" 
edittype="select" 
sortable="true" 
editoptions="{
  dataUrl:'%{creativeSelect}', 
  multiple:true
}"/>
```

Here `campaignCreatives` is a list attibute and I'm trying to display in a column.
I'm trying to call a function on jsonmap but its not working, so if anybody please can tell me how to call a function on jsonmap property of a jquery grid column in `struts2-jquery-grid`.

Comment: is there anybody who can help me in this problem....:(

Comment: i just want help in how to use jsonmap as a function in struts2-jquery-grid plugin